# Ubuntu 16.04 Unresponsive every 10 minutes for 2 minutes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, freeze

I have a Ubuntu server running Apache2 and Mysql 5.7 which has been working great for about a year and is acting oddly as of yesterday. It seemed to go offline for a few minutes and then it was back. It happened one more time later but then was fine.

During it's "downtime" I am unable to get mysql, ssh or apache to respond, but ping does.

I checked top to see what the server load was, and all numbers were low, so it didn't seem like it had just finished up a big job

```
top - 12:23:04 up 26 days, 21:59,  2 users,  load average: 0.28, 0.18, 0.19
Tasks: 387 total,   1 running, 386 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 82331792 total, 75453456 free,  5990408 used,   887928 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 19401728+total, 19397209+free,    45172 used. 75653488 avail Mem
```

The system has dual `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz` has plenty of memory and the OS is on an LSI Megaraid with 4 disks in a RAID 10, the data directories are using a PCI SSD with excellent read-write speeds.

I thought maybe at first it was a DDoS attack, but checking like this:

```
netstat -an|grep ESTABLISHED|awk '{print $5}'|awk -F: '{print $1}'|sort|uniq -c|awk '{ printf("%s\t%s\t",$2,$1); for (i = 0; i < $1; i++) {printf("*")}; print ""}'
        26      **************************
127.0.0.1       6       ******
204.23.45.6     2       **
34.237.124.252  1       *
61.72.21.21   8       ********
```

Nothing pops out to me. I tried pinging from another computer in the same cabinet using the public IP and there was never any lapse.

I checked the raid status and it is good, lots of free space as well.

While typing this out it froze 3-4 times, so trying to catch it in the act I started up `top` and set the refresh to 0.5 seconds and now it has been a couple hours without it freezing. What should I check next?